# recurDescents(p) and recurAncestors(p)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a Python script with two functions. One function is to return the descendants children of (p) and Take (p) and return ancestors of (p).

I made a script that returns the children of (p).

```
parent = [("Homer","Bart"),("Homer","Lisa"),("Abe","Homer"),("Bart","Jim"),("Jim","Kim"),("Lisa","Lora")]

def child(p): #definition of child function()
    result = []    
    for x in parent:
        if x[0] == p:
            print(x[1])
            result.append(x[1])


        return result

def grandChild (p):
    result = []
    children = child(p)
    for x in children:
        for y in parent:
            if x == y[0]:
                result.append(y(1))
            return result



p = "Homer"
children = child(p) # my caller question
print(p, " has child ", children)
```

I just can't figure out what to do.

Comment: Your return statements are indented wrong.  Put them outside the for loops.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statements are in the wrong places.  They should be outside the loops:

```
def f():
    for loop
        stuff
    return ...
```

If you want a slightly more concise version:

```
#find children of parent p
[child for parent, child in list_of_parents if parent == p]
#find parent of child c
[parent for parent, child in list_of_parents if child == c]
```

Comment: It returns the answer:Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) on Windows (64 bits).
This is the Pyzo interpreter with integrated event loop for TK.
Type 'help' for help, type '?' for a list of *magic* commands.
Running script: 
Bart
Homer  has child  ['Bart'] :for the original script. I cant find a good definition for the recurDescents(p) and recurAncestors(p) anywhere online.